# Refresh a div from link_to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbye that is trying to do little things in Rails, at the moment I have created an app that build some links and I want to refresh the content of a Div when they are clicked.

In my application.html.erb I have the layout with the next head:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

(I have read about change the second line for :defaults but if do that I get a 404 error defauls.js)

I have an index.html.erb that render a partial with this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'masvisitadas' %>
```

In my _masvisitadas.html.erb I have the code that generate the links:

```
<%= link_to solution.SolutionName, "/soluciones/despliega/" + solution.Id.to_s, :remote=>true %>
```

This generate the next html:

```
http://localhost:3000/soluciones/despliega/501D0000000QWp6IAG
```

In my controller I have the next def:

```
def despliega
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

Finally I have created despliega.js.erb:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render('despliega')) %>";
  $("#customTopLeft").prepend(html)
$("customTopLeft").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'despliega')) %>");

});
```

In the log of the web server when i click a link it seems all going well:

```
Started GET "/soluciones/despliega/501D0000000QXM0IAO" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-
20 12:16:53 +0200
Processing by SolucionesController#despliega as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"501D0000000QXM0IAO"}
  Rendered soluciones/_despliega.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered soluciones/_despliega.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered soluciones/despliega.js.erb (15.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 31.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And in the firebug I can see the call with any error but nothing happends.
This is killing my head :) Thanks in advance for any help here.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in _despliega.html.erb?

Try changing despliega.js.erb to this (and only this):

```
$('#customTopLeft').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'despliega') %>");
```

Edit - oh, and make sure you have the jQuery libraries included ..

Comment: In _despliega.html.erb I only have a text Hellou World, I have tried changing my js.erb but with the same result, any error but nothing is refreshed. I have this lines in my application.js I have this lines //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .